# What is flat bundling and why is Rollup better at this than Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundler, rollupjs

I have recently been looking into [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) and seeing how it differs from Webpack and other bundlers. One thing I came across was that it is better for libraries because of "flat bundling". This is based on a [tweet](https://twitter.com/trueadm/status/849367888683307008) and from [a recent PR for React to utilize Rollup](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/9327).

> In my experience, Rollup is better at building libraries due to better optimizations around flat bundling (e.g. hoisting). 1/2
>
> Webpack 2 may be better for you if you're bundling apps with code-splitting etc though. 2/2

I'm not entirely sure I understand what that means though. What does flat bundling refer to? I know Rollup's documentation mentions [treeshaking](https://github.com/rollup/rollup#tree-shaking) to help reduce bundle size but [Webpack also has a way of doing this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/). Perhaps I just don't understand the concept entirely.

Please note this is NOT a comparison question regarding Rollup vs Webpack. For people interested in that, there is a [comparison chart for that by Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/comparison.html). This is primarily asking what flat bundling is? And potentially what does Rollup do internally to achieve this?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**Edit: Rollup supports code splitting - [read article](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#code-splitting)**

**Edit: Webpack now supports scope hoisting in some situations — [read the blog post here](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-3-official-release-15fd2dd8f07b)**

We probably all have different definitions for this stuff, but I think flat bundling simply means 'taking your modules and turning them into a single bundle' — i.e, the 'flat' is redundant. The big difference in React 16 is that you'll consume a premade bundle by default, rather than your app being responsible for bundling React's source modules (though there was always a [prebuilt UMD bundle of React available](https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js), built with Browserify).

Rather, the big difference between the two is what happens *at the module boundaries*. The way webpack works is that it wraps each module in a function, and creates a bundle that implements a loader and a module cache. At runtime, each of those module functions is evaluated in turn to populate the module cache. This architecture has lots of advantages — it makes it possible to implement advanced features like code-splitting and on-demand loading, and hot module replacement (HMR).

Rollup takes a different approach — it puts all your code at the same level (rewriting identifiers as necessary to avoid conflicts between variable names etc). This is often referred to as '**scope hoisting**'. Because of it, there's no per-module overhead, and no per-bundle overhead. Your bundle is guaranteed to be smaller, and will also evaluate faster because there's less indirection (more information on that — [The cost of small modules](https://nolanlawson.com/2016/08/15/the-cost-of-small-modules/)). The trade-off is that this behaviour relies on ES2015 module semantics, and it means that some of webpack's advanced features are much harder to implement (e.g. Rollup doesn't support code-splitting, at least not yet!).

In short, webpack is *generally* a better fit for apps, and Rollup is *generally* a better fit for libraries.

I've put together a [small gist illustrating the differences](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/79a02519fb00837e8d5a4b24355881c0). You can also get a feel for Rollup's output by [tinkering with the Rollup REPL](https://rollupjs.org/repl).

Comment: Incredible answer. Thanks a lot :) makes it a lot clearer!

Comment: It looks like you wrote a [really awesome medium post also about Rollup and Webpack](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c). I'd thought I'd give it a shout out :)

Comment: this answer may need an update w.r.t to webpack 3, which has introduced scope hoisting. https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-3-official-release-15fd2dd8f07b

Comment: Gonna also add that [webpack 3 documentation for ModuleConcatenationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/) talks about this very well.

Comment: You can combine rollup with gulp4 with gulp-better-rollup and can pretty much do anything with rollup you might need to, utilizing gulp where you might want to. And you can write gulp files in es6 via babel and a gulpfile.babel.js file instead of a gulpfile.js file.  This means you can split your build into separate pieces and clean things up nicely.  I've basically migrated completely to this setup for all apps and libraries.

Comment: Nice explanation :-)